# Selection difficulties

Tags: selection-tools

I'm in edit, I've got wire frame on, I've got xray on and when I try to select the top crab claw by drawing a square over it it only selects some of it.  When I try to add faces its only adding them sometimes.I want the crab claw as a a separate object[image]

Comment: That's a weird one... Doesn't even look like you're in edit mode, but you clearly are. There should be the vertices and face centres visible. What happens if you only select the very top vertex, the one at the tip of the claw, then hit `CTRL +` a few time?

Comment: Try just selecting just the vertices icon (1 on the keyboard). At the moment you have both vertex and face selection activated (both icons hilighted) and it sounds as if they're interfering with each other.

Comment: None of these solutions worked.  I went back to an earlier version of the claw before I'd merged some points together.  This time it worked.  Obviously something went wrong when I tried to simplify by merging points.

Comment: Hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/